# Cannot delete folder using with rmdir function

Tags: php, rmdir

I have a problem deleting the selected folder in the folder path. I am using XAMPP, and won't delete the selected folder path is `C:\xampp\htdocs\delete_folder\test\abc`, but the below coding is cannot work to delete the folder. I think because inside the `abc` folder got another folder.

I am referring to this link to do the rmdir function: https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.rmdir.php

Below is a sample coding in the index.php, that mean every time I am refreshing the page, if work it can delete the selected folder:

```php
<?php
$dir ="test/abc";
function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        return unlink($dir);
    }

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        if (!deleteDirectory($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return rmdir($dir);
}
?>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: could you kindly insert the error stack that php generates

Comment: Where are you calling the function from?   The program you have here doesn't do anything but define a function.

Comment: From that page you linked: "_The directory must be empty..._"

Comment: @RufusVS Ok, thanks. Can you give a sample?

Comment: @brombeer Yes, show `The directory must be empty`

Comment: Are you asking us for  an example of where _you_ call the function you've posted? That's a bit backwards. We don't know where or how you're calling this function. Not trying to be rude, but just so we know at what level you are at (based on your comment), do you know what functions are and how they work?

Comment: Since the folder must be empty, this: _"I think because inside the abc folder got another folder."_ would definitely be an issue. If a folder contains another folder, it's not empty.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Or you have another good idea can replace my code?

Comment: The way to do it is to `scandir(...)`, get all paths, delete each path (by directory or filetype as well) recursively furthest out first, then remove the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written, are you expecting the line:

```
$dir ="test/abc";
```

To pass the name `test/abc` to your function that
starts with:

```
function deleteDirectory($dir) {
```

and execute the function? That is not the way functions work.

The `$dir` is a function argument and has absolutely no relationship with
the `$dir` you defined just before it.  Your code should look more like:

```
<?php

function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        return unlink($dir);
    }

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        if (!deleteDirectory($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return rmdir($dir);
}

deleteDirectory("test/abc");

?>
```

See?  The function is defined, then it gets call with the desired argument.
(I hope my php syntax is correct here, I rarely use php.  But the general idea is the same in all languages)

Comment: A function is hoisted, so it just needs to be declared in an earlier (included) scope or within the current scope (anywhere). https://3v4l.org/ORpDF

Comment: Thank you @JaredFarrish.  I should have mentioned this isn't the only way functions are defined and called, considering the lack of experience of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows shell/cmd has a command `rmdir` that can remove folders with content. Use

```
exec('rmdir FOLDERNAME /s /q');
```

Open a shell/cmd on Windows and type `rmdir /?` and you'll see an explanation of the parameters:

`/s` removes folders with content inside

`/q` won't ask for confirmation.

Use with caution!